# PHP Cronjob In Windows 7

Tags: php

Hye alls.. 
this is my code that cronjob will do..

```
$query = "UPDATE program SET status_penilaian = 1  WHERE tarikh_buka = CURDATE()";
$hasil = mysql_query($query);
```

question is.. how to setting to cronjob this php file in task schedule?

i'm using PHP Version 5.2.8

Comment: First of all: You should update your PHP version

Comment: PHP Version 5.2.8 can't do this cronjob?

Comment: _Every_ tool, that you can start from command line, can be set up as crobjob (what includes PHP back to .. don't know .. 3(?)). However: Its ooooold!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you do your own research?

You can do this straight in MySQL by creating an [event](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/)

OR

Use [PyCron](http://www.kalab.com/freeware/pycron/pycron.htm), there has been some good success using this in Windows

OR

The first listing in [google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=mysql%20cron%20query&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&redir_esc=&ei=6mCpT_aJA5CN4gSgh90d#hl=en&client=safari&rls=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=mysql%20cron%20query%20windows&oq=mysql%20cron%20query%20windows&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=serp.3...1652.2653.0.2709.8.6.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0.TOo7qJ4Jhos&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=1c47a8cd7926411e&biw=1920&bih=1018) came up with this:

http://lists.mysql.com/eventum-users/1342

> 1. Use Windows Schedule Task. (not that good)
> 2. Use a web based service:
>              a. http://www.cronjobs.org (ok but anything above 13 minutes and you have to pay - very small amounts but it does work)
>
>    ```
>        b. http://www.webcron.org (ok but limited to running cron jobs at hourly intervals as the minimum)
>    ```
> 3. Visualcron (http://www.visualcron.com/) GUI windows app - ok but I found it difficult to get it work properly. Support non-existent -
>      never received emails to my queries. You may have better luck.
> 4. CRONw - (http://cronw.sourceforge.net/ & http://sourceforge.net/projects/cronw/) Excellent - works and is
>      configured like a cron job on Unix. No Windows installer yet but will
>      be released in v2.1. Requires PERL to be installed (recommend
>      ActiveStates Perl install).

Comment: ok thanks alll... i have updated my PHP version.. it's now work... thank you all.... thank u Sandeep Bansal... i will study... it' took times to understand... i'm student... new too php.. tq all....